# Texture painting texture maps

Tags: materials

When texture painting material maps, like displacement or base color on the surface of an object, is there a way to overlay them to see both maps so you know how they fit over each other?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make some temporary modifications to the material and then use a material or rendered preview, possibly in an extra 3D viewport:

[image]

You can texture paint in either preview.  Unfortunately, the other preview won't update until the stroke completes.